# Travis rebooting pretty often during runs with Docker involved

Tags: docker, travis-ci

I am using a matrix where each build runs a particular Docker image.
I see frequent reboots during the build procedure or test run of my application. Not sure if this is related to Docker but what could explain frequent reboots?

```
Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28
/opt/python/2.7.10/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
  warnings.warn(msg)

Broadcast message from root@testing-gce-54221373-0567-4343-a9b0-fb9eb10895c4
    (unknown) at 13:06 ...
The system is going down for power off NOW!
```

Answer (score 0):

I am on the infrastructure team at Travis and wanted to give you an explanation as to why you were seeing this.

For our Trusty beta, http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/trusty-ci-environment/, we're using Google Compute Engine to run the build VMs. The VMs we're using right now are provisioned as pre-emptible VMs, https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preemptible, which means Google can shut them down at will.

We normally handle this case like any number of other failure scenarios that might require us to restart a build but we found that this particular scenario wasn't being handled properly in all cases, so builds were being marked as failed when they should have been restarted.

You should no longer see this happening and we should automatically restart a build when this scenario occurs. We're also looking into how we can better track this particular scenario in our metrics, as right now it's just counted as a single "requeued job" metric that covers a range of possible sources for requeue.

Comment: I'm starting to see this in my builds as well.  Is this still an issue?